# C Programming - Two for loops to recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I was trying to make recursive function that would simulate two for loops. So, function would have to do this:

```
int recursion(int n, int i, int j)
{
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

but, i want it to be recursive. I tried something like:

```
int recursion(int n, int i, int j)
{
    if(i<n)
    {
        if(j<n)
        {
            printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
            recursion(n, i+1, j+1);
        }
        recursion(n, i+1, i+1+1);
    }
}
```

I would call recursive one in main like

```
recursion(10, 0, 1);
```

but output is not the same for those two version of function. May anyone tell me where am I mistaking with the recursive one?

Comment: Your innermost `recursion(n,i+1` is incorrect. `i` doesn't change inside the `for(j)` loop, therefore you shouldn't be incrementing it in the recursive version at that point.

Comment: Sidenote: It would be better to start from 'n' and recurse with descending values. That way you don't have to pass `n`.

Comment: Is it intentional that you ignore the `j` argument value passed to the function but instead overwrite it in your loop?

Comment: @MarcB I tried to change, but output still is not the same as function with for loops. This is output of function with for loops:
0 1
0 2
1 2
and this is output of recursive one:
0 1
0 2
1 2
1 2
1 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simulating nested `for` loops, you should only increment one of your counter variables for each recursive call, depending on whether you're "in" the inner or outer loop.  Also, the outer loop calls need to reset the inner loop counter to zero.

```
/* i for outer loop, j for inner loop, both going 0 to n-1 */
void recursion(int n, int i, int j)
{
  if (i < n) {
    if (j < n) {
      // inner loop when j < n
      printf("i=%d, j=%d\n",i,j); // inner loop body
      recursion(n, i, j+1); // increment inner counter only!
    } else { // when j has reached n...
      // outer loop, which restarts inner loop
      recursion(n, i+1, 0); // increment outer counter, reset inner
                            // since we're starting a new inner loop
    }
  }
}
```

If called initially as `recursion(N, 0, 0)` this should be roughly equivalent to:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    printf("i=%d, j=%d\n", i, j);
  }
}
```

...except that it doesn't account for modifications of `i` within the inner loop (none happen in these examples, but if the inner loop did set `i` larger than `N`, the recursive version would break both loops without finishing the inner loop first).

Comment: This is what i was looking for! I edited the code a bit to match my for loops but it works! Thank you, that is what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether you can replace two `for` loops with one recursive function. You can easily make it work with couple of recursive functions.

```
void recursion2(int n1, int n2)
{
   if ( n2 >= 0 )
   {
      recursion2(n1, n2-1);
      // Do whatever you need to do with the variables.
      func(n1, n2);
   }
}

void recursion1(int n1, int n2)
{
   if ( n1 >= 0 )
   {
      recursion1(n1-1, n2);
      recursion2(n1, n2);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

recursion of two `for` loops can be done this way:

```
void recursion(int n,int i,int j) //void since you return no value
{
    if(i<n)
    {
        if(j<n)
        {
            printf("%d %d\n",i,j);
            recursion(n,i,++j); //never use post increment
        }
            else
            recursion(n,++i,0);
    }
}
```

**Sample input:** *(arguments are sent from* `main()` *function)*

```
5 1 1
```

**Sample output:**

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
2 0
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 4
3 0
3 1
3 2
3 3
3 4
4 0
4 1
4 2
4 3
4 4
```